# Wierdness with jQuery's parent and tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding a place holder div in my code so it can later be replaced by some html. This is for a little templating engine I am writing (something like handlebars.js) so I don't have any control over what the parent element is.

Something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <div id="4FEA2092330"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

if I get the parent of the placeholder div I get the ul which is great.

However if the placeholder is inside a table like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <div id="4FEA2092330"></div>
    </table>
</div>
```

The parent of the placeholder div is the container div not the table.

Further testing shows that if I use a tr in the table (instead of the div) the parent routine returns the table.

Any ideas why that would happen and how I might be able to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is invalid.  A table can't directly contain a `<div>` like that. The way to avoid the undesired behavior is to build a proper table.

I *think* it'd work to wrap your `<div>` in a `<td>`.  The necessary other parts of the table will be implicitly added around that.

Comment: Thanks Pointy! I agree that semantically a table can't hold a div but I was hoping that I could do this structurally. I.e. as long as all the start and end tags match up then it is wellFormed. I'm also pretty sure that a div inside a UL is also invalid markup

Comment: @niggle well browsers (some of them) cope with funny markup by selectively ignoring parts of it. However it depends on exactly how the markup is wrong, and what tags are involved.

Comment: Alright!!!! By changing my placeholder to <td><div id="4FEA2092330"></div></td> it seems to work now.  Thanks for the suggestion.